# Using QUnit for testing on dynamic view, determine whether an element has been rendered in the DOM

Tags: html, jquery, qunit

In my application, which uses jQuery, I'm working on unit testing. For my application I am creating unit test cases using QUnit , which I am still learning.
I am returning a dynamic view from my controller method via an AJAX call. The challenge is that the Test case assertion function cannot locate the Element in the DOM.
Here is the code I have so far attempted.

```
QUnit.module('Lookup', function () {
    // GLOBAL VARS TO BE USED FOR TESTING
    var userId = "johnDoe";
    const userType = { type: "user" };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search?id=' + userId + '',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log("User Profile Found" + res);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("Error Fetching Record..." + err);
        }
    });

    // CALLING THE Search CONTROLLER METHOD TO GET User PROFILES
    QUnit.test("Search for User Profile UI with user details", function (assert) {
        var done = assert.async();
        Promise.resolve().then(function (res) {
            assert.equal($("#user-search").is(":visible"), true, "User Search Result Shown");
        });
        done();
    })
```

I have tried async methods and tried placing the script above the DOM but it still is not able to give a success result.